# Crash in SwiftyJSON during string comparison: swift_unknownRetain

Tags: swift, crash, crashlytics, swifty-json

I'm switching on a flag from the server in order to determine what type of object to instantiate. Each type is a subclass of the return type (`Snack`, in the example.) My guess is that the whole subclass thing is irrelevant to the main issue, but I include it for completeness.

The trouble is that I'm pretty consistently getting a crash reported from Crashlytics on the `case "chips":` line. In order to simplify parsing in my initializers, I'm wrapping the server response in a SwiftyJSON `JSON`. This all worked fine in testing.

```
class func fromJSON(json: JSON) -> Snack {
    switch json["SnackName"] {
    case "chips":   // CRASH OCCURS HERE
        return BagOChips(json: json)
    case "apple":
        return Apple(json: json)
    default:
        return Spam(json: json)
    }
}
```

Specifically, the crash is occurring at "SwiftyJSON.swift:1013" (marked below). Crashlytics describes it as "EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000093a4bec8" and "swift_unknownRetain + 32".

```
public func ==(lhs: JSON, rhs: JSON) -> Bool {

    switch (lhs.type, rhs.type) {
    case (.Number, .Number):
        return (lhs.object as NSNumber) == (rhs.object as NSNumber)
    case (.String, .String):
        return (lhs.object as String) == (rhs.object as String) // CRASH REALLY OCCURS HERE
    case (.Bool, .Bool):
        return (lhs.object as Bool) == (rhs.object as Bool)
    case (.Array, .Array):
        return (lhs.object as NSArray) == (rhs.object as NSArray)
    case (.Dictionary, .Dictionary):
        return (lhs.object as NSDictionary) == (rhs.object as NSDictionary)
    case (.Null, .Null):
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

Any idea why this is failing and what I might be able to do to correct it in our next release?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem, and boy was it obscure!

TL;DR - Avoid SwiftyJSON's `==` function entirely by replacing

```
switch json["SnackName"]
```

with

```
switch json["SnackName"].stringValue
```

That's probably a good idea in general, but the reason it's necessary appears to be a bug deep in the bowels of how Swift + Foundation handle strings. I've filed an open radar [here](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5314531127459840).

All it takes to reproduce this problem is Xcode 6.1, SwiftyJSON, and the following sample code that I submitted to Apple:

```
let d = NSDictionary(dictionary: ["foo": "bar"])
let j = JSON(d)

switch (j["foo"]) {
case "bar":
   println("> No crash!")
default:
   println("> default")
}
```

Then throw in these logging statements in your copy of SwiftyJSON.

```
public func ==(lhs: JSON, rhs: JSON) -> Bool {
  // Next 2 lines added just for SwiftyCrasher test project.
  println( "> Left: \(_stdlib_getTypeName(lhs.object))" )
  println( "> Right: \(_stdlib_getTypeName(rhs.object))" )

  switch (lhs.type, rhs.type) {
  case (.Number, .Number):
      return (lhs.object as NSNumber) == (rhs.object as NSNumber)
  case (.String, .String):
  ...
}
```

This shows the following console output, just before the crash:

```
> Left: _TtCSs19_NSContiguousString
> Right: _TtCSs19_NSContiguousString
```

Again, in Debug mode, this *doesn't* crash. Boxing "foo" and "bar" in NSString, or changing `j["foo"]` to `j["foo"].stringValue` also prevent a crash.